# Removing a row by string-matching in R regardless of whether it exists or not

Tags: r

I am trying to remove a row in a dataframe based on string matching.  I'm using:

```
data <- data[- grep("my_string", data$field1),]
```

When there's an actual row with the value `"my_string"` in `data$field1` this works as expected and it drops that row.  However, if there is no string "my_string", it creates an empty dataframe.  How to I do write this so that it allows for the possibility of the string to not exist, and still keeps my data frame intact?

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to use `grepl` and negate with `!`

```
data[!grepl("my_string", data$field1),]
```

Or another option is `setdiff` on `grep`

```
data[setdiff(seq_len(nrow(data)),  grep("my_string", data$field1)),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plain if statement.

```r
df <- data.frame(fieled = c("my_string", "my_string_not", "something", "something_else"),
                 numbers = 1:4)


result <- grep("gabriel", df$fieled)
if (length(result))
{
  df <- df[- result, ]
}

df

result <- grep("my_string", df$fieled)
if (length(result))
{
  df <- df[- result, ]
}

df
```